# OSX Connecting PHP to MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, macos

I have troubles at connecting PHP to MongoDB on my machine (OSX).
When I try to execute

```
$mongoDB = new Mongo();
```

I get an error on the page

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in ***** on line 5
```

When I type phpinfo() it doesn't list mongo drivers there.

What I've done so far?
I've installed mongo and its driver by using brew as following:

```
brew tap homebrew/php
brew install php56-mongodb
```

and added to my /etc/php.ini.default:

```
extension=php_mongodb.dll
```

Is there anything I did wrong? I'd very appreciate your answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could be a number of things. At command line, type `which php`, to confirm you have the right php configured. Then, type `php -v` , if there are any issues with loading libraries you will know. Finally, `php_mongodb.dll` is more than likely `php_mongodb.so`.

Comment: Hello @YvesLeBorg. `which php` gives me a path with a binary content I can't read. When I type -v I get `PHP 5.6.27 (cli) (built: Oct 15 2016 09:29:27) `... What to do now? I don't get it...

Comment: did you brew php ?  and it is very weird that `which` should give a binary path.

Comment: Yes I've brew php. And it tells me even that `homebrew/php/php55-mongodb` is even installed (green mark sign there when I type brew php again)

Comment: then you are using the wrong php ... the one distributed by apple. Try /usr/local/bin/php ...  -v(version) -m(modules) and sysinfo. To fix this, put /usr/local/bin as a PATH component, before /usr/bin

Comment: /usr/local/bin is already put before /usr/bin... :/

Comment: so, did you put `extension=php_mongodb.so` in `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini` ?

Comment: Still not working and yes I've restarted apache.

Comment: getting new error now: 'PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library... php_mongodb.so.... image not found in <b>Unknown</b> on line'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution here...

After writing code like this (latest mongo driver) it worked!

```
<?php
class DatabaseAPI {
    private $mongoClient;

    function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->mongoClient = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I had to use latest library. Using $a = new Mongo() wasn't supported anymore.